# Which chemical propellant combination has the highest theoretical isp?

Tags: fuel, specific-impulse

That is disregarding practical factors like making a bomb rather than a rocket in the case of using acetylene+ozone.

I know that the highest isp achieved was 542 with lithium, hydrogen, and fluorine. I assume that the acetylene and ozone combination would be more in the range 600. How high can that number go?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but my instinct says the oxidizer will be [Chlorine Triflouride](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chlorine_trifluoride).  That stuff has a *reputation*.

Comment: Related https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/17129/is-there-a-maximum-isp-for-exothermic-chemical-reaction-rockets?rq=1

Comment: Given your requirements, currently, I believe [1‐diazidocarbamoyl‐5‐azidotetrazole](http://blogs.sciencemag.org/pipeline/archives/2013/01/09/things_i_wont_work_with_azidoazide_azides_more_or_less) as a monopropellant fits the bill. With 1493kJ/mol, it's really something! Unfortunately it's very hard to find *anything* that doesn't make it explode.

Answer (score 6):

What about monatomic hydrogen? The bond energy of $H_2$ is 436 kJ/mol, but a mol is only 2g, so you have about 218 MJ/kg of available energy. If you could get 100% of that into axial kinetic energy of the $H_2$ that would be an exhaust velocity of around $20 km/s$ for an $I_{sp}$ around 2000s. Some would inevitably be lost as waste heat, through thermal dissociation of the $H_2$ and as lateral KE, but four figures might still be within reach.

Of course it can only be stored for short periods as an extremely diffuse ultra-cold gas in a magnetic field, and I certainly would not like to try and pump it, but the question did specify no practical considerations.

A few years ago there were a number of [presentations](https://www.nasa.gov/pdf/637123main_Silvera_Presentation.pdf) and [articles](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1742-6596/215/1/012194/meta) around the idea that if metallic hydrogen is metastable, it could be a very powerful fuel (definitely four figure $I_{sp}$). That said, while there were some very hand-wavy arguments from physical principles and some obscure hints from experiments, there is no actual evidence that I know of that metallic hydrogen is metastable.

Of course if you had **very** strong tanks available, you could just store it under pressure to keep it stable.

Answer (score 3):

There is [a paper](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19860018652.pdf) that has looked at a number of tripropellant combinations, looking for the optimum theoretical ISP. The optimum appears to be Be/ H2/ O2, at 460 seconds at sea level. [This paper](https://thephysicsofspacex.files.wordpress.com/2016/07/isp-upper-limits.pdf) states the theoretical max of Hydrolox is 532, with the additional 69 that the first paper state by adding beryllium, just over 600 is theoretically possible, in a vacuum. But using Beryllium is basically impossible as a rocket fuel, at least as we know it today.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

"Li+F2+H2 has been *measured* at 542s"

https://yarchive.net/space/rocket/fuels/li-f-h.html